# Using return query in Postgres 9.0 function with composite type

Tags: database, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in Postgres which return a setof composite type. When returning I am only able do it with `return next;` but not with `return query` command, why is that?

```
 CREATE TYPE return_type AS
   (paramname character varying,
    value character varying);

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(i_param1 character varying, i_param2 character varying)
      RETURNS SETOF return_type AS

    --this works just fine returning two rows
    r.paramname:='row1';
    r.value:='myvalue1';
    return next r;        
    r.paramname:='row1';
    r.value:='myvalue1';
    return next r;
    return;

    --  with this command I do not get a single row attached in the resultset
    return query
    select 'row1' as paraName,'myvalue1' as value
    UNION ALL
    select 'row2' as paraName,'myvalue2' as value;
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, even in Postgres 8.4:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(i_param1 varchar, i_param2 varchar)
  RETURNS SETOF return_type AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 'row1'::varchar, 'myvalue1'::varchar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'row2','myvalue2';
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Your original should only return an exception, because of type mismatch. You need to **cast** the string literals to matching types. On the other hand, column aliases are irrelevant here: not visible outside the function body.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/17c02/1)

Comment: Well @erwin when getting the function result I have not had any exceptions so far regarding type mistamatch, so I do not think that is my problem. It is just returning 0 rows when should be returning one row.Regarding the aliases, is something I am not authorized to change.

Comment: @Douglas: The aliases inside the query don't *require* changes. they are just noise. As for the result: Have you had a look at the provided fiddle? It obviously works in Postgres 8.4 and 9.1. Don't have any 9.0 installations at hand any more. 9.0 wasn't a particularly popular release and is getting old now. If that doesn't solve your problem, please provide a *complete* function definition - like you should have to begin with - so we can try to reproduce your findings.

Comment: Yup you are right @Erwin, pitfully I need to use that version of Postgres because compatibility issues with newer versions of Postgres from the platform used. I ran some tests and looks like you are correct I needed to cast the string literals though for some reason it did not throw any error. Thanks!